# correct package name for glibc in Amazon Linux EBS

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, lxml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to install glibc-devel package for my EBS python 2.7 64 bits at AWS.

Different from any other solutions, I have to install python27-devel instead of python-devel, postgresql93-devel instead of postgresql-devel, so I was wondering the correct name for glibc-devel package because with that name it seems to skipt the installation yum packages (.ebextensions/config file).

The main problem is to install lxml from pip packages. I successfully installed libxslt-devel and libxml2-devel in that server, also gcc and patch.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my question, the package name is: glibc-devel.i686